# How we can create Add more button for Dropdown list in html and how to store value of selected value form dropdown list in variable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have create one dropdown list in html you can see my code and i want to add (Add more) button in html
 if user want to add more dropdown list for more values they can add by (Add more) button.
And how we can store selected value from these dropdown list in variables.for retrieve data by sql query from table.

```js
Java script code 

<script>
$(document).ready(function ()
{

    $(document).on('change', '.text-two', function ()
    {   // when the attraction_OR_activity dropdown is selected
        //var S1value = $(this).parents('.multi-field');
        //$(S1value).find('.').html(''); // emptying the selections of 3rd dropdown list if there was any selections were made before.

        /* saving selected values in variables */
        var selected_scondition = $(scondition).find('.text-one :selected').val();
        var selected_S1value = $(S1value).find('.text-two :selected').val();

        //colombo_attractions = new Array("Ganga Ramaya", "National Art Gallery", "Galle Face Green", "Arcade Indepentent Square");
        //colombo_activities = new Array("City Walk 2016", "Traditional Dance Competition 2016", "Local Spicy food");

       /* if (selected_destination == 'colombo' && selected_attraction_or_activity == 'attraction') {
            colombo_attractions.forEach(function (t) {
                $(destination).find('.populated_attr_or_activity').append('<option>' + t + '</option>');
            });
        }

        if (selected_destination == 'colombo' && selected_attraction_or_activity == 'activity') {
            colombo_activities.forEach(function (t) {
                $(destination).find('.populated_attr_or_activity').append('<option>' + t + '</option>');
            });
        }*/


    });

    /* ADD DESTINATION */
    $('.multi-field-wrapper').each(function ()
    {
        var $wrapper = $('.multi-fields', this);
        var x = 1;
        $(".add-field", $(this)).click(function (e)
        {
            x++;
            $($wrapper).append(
              '<div class="multi-field">
      &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
        <select class="text-one" name="Scondition[]" >
             <label><option value="AND" >AND</option></label>
             <label><option value="OR" >OR</option></label>
             <label><option value="AND NOT">NOT</option></label>
        </select>&emsp;&nbsp;
        
        <select class="text-two" name="S1value[]" >
        <label><option value="Claim"  >Claim - C</option></label>
        <label><option value="Title"  >Title - T</option></label>
        <label><option value="Description" >Description - D</option></label>
        <label><option value="Abstract" >Abstract - A</option></label>
        <label><option value="Application_No" >Application_Number - APN</option></label>
        <label><option value="Priority_Number"  >Priority_Number - PN</option></label>
        <label><option value="Record_Number" >Record_Number - RN</option></label>
        <label><option value="Priority_Date" >Priority_Date - PD</option></label>
        <label><option value="Application_Date">Application date</option></label> 
        <label><option value="Publication_Date"  >Publication_Date - PD</option></label>
        <label><option value="US_Class"  >US_Class - USC</option></label>
        <label><option value="IPC_Class" >IPC_Class - IPC</option></label>
        <label><option value="CPC_Class" >CPC_Class - CPC</option></label>
        <label><option value="Priority_Country_Code"  >Priority Country Code - PCC</option></label>
        <label><option value="Designate_States" >Designate_States - DS</option></label>
        <label><option value="Legal_Status_Current" >Legal_Status_Current - LSC</option></label>
        </select> 
     </div>
     <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your query here " name="Vname" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['Vname'])) { echo htmlentities($_POST['Vname']);
}?>" size="60" required /></div>');
        });

             $($wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function (e)
             { //user click on remove text
                  e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
              })
    });
});
</script>
```

```html
HTML CODE

div class="multi-field-wrapper">
      <button type="button" class="add-field">Add More</button>        
      <div class="multi-fields">
      <div class="multi-field">
      &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
        <select class="text-one" name="Scondition[]" >
             <label><option value="AND" >AND</option></label>
             <label><option value="OR" >OR</option></label>
             <label><option value="AND NOT">NOT</option></label>
        </select>&emsp;&nbsp;
        
        <select class="text-two" name="S1value[]" >
        <label><option value="Claim"  >Claim - C</option></label>
        <label><option value="Title"  >Title - T</option></label>
        <label><option value="Description" >Description - D</option></label>
        <label><option value="Abstract" >Abstract - A</option></label>
        <label><option value="Application_No" >Application_Number - APN</option></label>
        <label><option value="Priority_Number"  >Priority_Number - PN</option></label>
        <label><option value="Record_Number" >Record_Number - RN</option></label>
        <label><option value="Priority_Date" >Priority_Date - PD</option></label>
        <label><option value="Application_Date">Application date</option></label> 
        <label><option value="Publication_Date"  >Publication_Date - PD</option></label>
        <label><option value="US_Class"  >US_Class - USC</option></label>
        <label><option value="IPC_Class" >IPC_Class - IPC</option></label>
        <label><option value="CPC_Class" >CPC_Class - CPC</option></label>
        <label><option value="Priority_Country_Code"  >Priority Country Code - PCC</option></label>
        <label><option value="Designate_States" >Designate_States - DS</option></label>
        <label><option value="Legal_Status_Current" >Legal_Status_Current - LSC</option></label>
        </select> 
     </div>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your query here " name="Vname" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['Vname'])) { echo htmlentities($_POST['Vname']);  // always filter outputs of external data
}
?>" size="60" required />
  </div>
```

I want to add Same Dropdown list by (Add more) and storing the selected value in a variable.

Comment: 1) It's `<label>` not `<lable>` 2) That's moot anyway as you cannot have a `label` as a child of a `select` or `option`.

Comment: I don't see your code?

Comment: i am adding code but it is not adding hole ?

Comment: Please see my code